# JOOQ MULTISET constructor

Tags: spring-boot, jooq

```
context.select(
      AUTHOR.FIRST_NAME,
      AUTHOR.LAST_NAME,
      multiset(
          selectDistinct(
              BOOK.language().CD,
              BOOK.language().DESCRIPTION)
          .from(BOOK)
          .where(BOOK.AUTHOR_ID.eq(AUTHOR.ID))
      ).as("books"),
      multiset(
          selectDistinct(BOOK_TO_BOOK_STORE.BOOK_STORE_NAME)
          .from(BOOK_TO_BOOK_STORE)
          .where(BOOK_TO_BOOK_STORE.tBook().AUTHOR_ID
              .eq(AUTHOR.ID))
      ).as("book_stores"))
  .from(AUTHOR)
  .orderBy(AUTHOR.ID)
  .fetch();
```

I was not able to get multiset it. It is throwing the error "Cannot resolve symbol multiset".
Which dependencies should I add get get multiset constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two most popular explanations for this problem are:

#### 1. You're not using the correct jOOQ version

Since you're using Spring Boot, you might be pulling in jOOQ 3.14 instead of 3.15, when the new `MULTISET` operator has been introduced. Spring Boot 2.x won't upgrade to jOOQ versions more recent than 3.14 anymore, because the jOOQ 3.15 Open Source Edition has a JDK baseline of Java 11, and Spring Boot 2.x still requires Java 8 (Spring Boot 3.0 increases its own baselibe to Java 17, fixing this limitation)

[But you can easily override the jOOQ dependency introduced by the `spring-boot-starter-jooq` as explained in this blog post here](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-use-jooqs-commercial-distributions-with-spring-boot/). If you're using Maven, just check your dependencies using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

#### 2. You're missing the usual static imports

All of the jOOQ manual makes the usual assumptions of you declaring a few static imports, including the most important one:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

Because `multiset()` as documented in the manual is just short for `DSL.multiset()`, assuming the above static import. [See also this section of the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/getting-started/the-manual/).